# Contraction Map (Fredholm integral type)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

I have been stuck on this problem for a little while. I think the proof might be similar to that of proving the Fredhom integral of the second type, however I am not sure. I am a little confused on the idea behind this proof.

$[a,b]$ is a closed interval in $R$ and let $A$ and $K$ be continuous real-valued functions on $[a,b]$ and

{$(x,y) \in  E^2: x,y \in [a,b]$}.

$W \in C([a,b])$, and $F(W) \in C([a,b])$ by  $(F(W))(x$) = A(x) + 
$\int_{a}^{b} K(x,y)W(y)dy$

I have already shown the continuity of $F(W)$. However, I am now trying to show that if $|(b-a)K(x,y)| < 1$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$ then $F$ is a contraction map and thus there exists a unique $p \in C([a,b])$ such that

p(x) = A(x) + $\int_{a}^{b} K(x,y)p(y)dy$

Proof for understanding would be much appreciated. I understand the concept but the proof is throwing me off.

Comment: How is $A$ defined? And what is $\{(x,y) \in  E^2: x,y \in [a,b]\}$? Does it have a name? Where do you use it?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $(b - a)|K(x,y)| < 1$ for all $x,y\in [a,b]$. Let $C := (b - a)\sup_{x,y\in [a,b]} |K(x,y)|$ Since $K$ is continuous on the rectangle $[a,b]\times [a,b]$, there exist $x_0, y_0\in [a,b]$ such that $C = (b - a)|K(x_0,y_0)|$ Thus $0 \le C < 1$. For all $U, W\in C([a,b])$,

\begin{align}\|F(U) - F(W)\| &= \sup_{x\in [a,b]}\left|\int_a^b K(x,y)[U(y) - W(y)]\, dy\right|\\
&\le \sup_{x\in [a,b]}\int_a^b |K(x,y)| |U(y) - W(y)|\, dy \\
&\le \sup_{x\in [a,b]}\int_a^b \frac{C}{b-a} \|U - W\|\, dy \\
&= C\|U - W\|.
\end{align}

Therefore, $F$ is a contraction mapping of $C[a,b]$.

Comment: what did you define U to be?

Comment: $U$ is an element of $C[a,b]$.

Comment: thanks this helps a lot and makes sense, since it is a contraction mapping we have a unique fixed point (proposition is in my book as well). However, how come the point is equivalent to A + the integral? I am very confused at this step

Comment: Because if $p(x)$ is the fixed point, then $p(x) = F(p)(x)$, and thus $p(x) = A(x) + \int_a^b K(x,y)p(y)\, dy$.